# remove view from supper view ios

Tags: ios, uiview, addsubview

i have a question about remove a subview from the supper view:
now i have a subview named : `subview1`
and then i add this subview in 2 other views:

`[supperview1 addSubview: subview1]`

and

`[suppertview2 addSubview: subview1]`

... i only know method `removeFromSupperview` to remove a subview out of supperview, but in this case i want remove subview1 out of supperview1 but still is subview of supperview2.... how can i do it ?

Comment: Have you try addSubView like that?Only supperview2 display subview1. Or you do it in the for loop?

Answer (score 4):

you code is wrong .

if you use

```
[supperview1 addSubview: subview1]
```

and then

```
[suppertview2 addSubview: subview1]
```

the `subview1` wil only added on the `suppertview2` , so the `subview1` only is the `suppertview2s subview`

Apple said:

> Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview
>   and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous
>   superview before making the receiver its new superview.